# I want to create custom signup form and add extra fields in Django default user model

Tags: python, django, forms, model

[image]

I want to add full name instead of first and last name and I also want to add some others fields like address, phone number, city.

```py
from django.forms import ModelForm
from django.contrib.auth.forms import UserCreationForm
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django import forms


class CreateUserForm(UserCreationForm):
    full_name=forms.CharField(max_length=50,required=True)
    phone_number=forms.CharField(widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={'type':'number'}))
    address=forms.CharField(max_length=200,required=True)
    city=forms.CharField(max_length=200,required=True)

    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ('username', 'email', 'password1', 'password2','full_name','phone_number','address','city')

    def register(self):
        self.save()
```

I created form by using this method. First, created forms.py for extra fields then inherited it. It is working; but still some fields disappear.

Comment: Which fields are missing?

Answer (score 0):

Because, you are adding additional fields to the default user model. First you have to
-Create a Custom User Model by using AbstractUser

Then
-Create a Custom Form for UserCreationForm

You can search google for:
Extend-existing-user-model-in-django